# 'Todo list' type of app for Windows AND Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, crossplatform

I need some recommendations on a good todo list type of app that works on Windows and Ubuntu. I would like to keep track of my assignment's due dates across both OS.

Comment: Cross-platform? Try out [softwarerecs.se] for software recommendation questions.

Comment: @muru thanks, I didn't know about that. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the suggestions. I ended up using a free open source app that is available on Ubuntu and Windows called Tasque. It can be found here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tasque

The app can store the list locally or via Remember the Milk's API (which is what I decided to use). It's simple and exactly what I was looking for. It says open in the taskbar area of Windows and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Google Chrome, I suggest you use an app with a Chrome extension support with it such as [Any.do](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/anydo-extension/kdadialhpiikehpdeejjeiikopddkjem?hl=en), which has a mobile app as well. I use this for daily use with my Ubuntu laptop, work desktop and my phone.

Answer (score 2):

Todoist - https://en.todoist.com/

More than basic functionality in the free version, runs on browsers or app for smartphones, Windows; integrates with Gmail, Thunderbird, Outlook, Firefox, Chrome ...

Has a handy Karma feature to show you how good you are with keeping to your lists.

Has priorities, groups / projects, tags, calendaring, etc ...

Answer (score 1):

Another choice would be [Wunderlist](https://www.wunderlist.com/) which comes with a dedicated [Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wunderlist-to-do-and-task/fjliknjliaohjgjajlgolhijphojjdkc?hl=de) that works on all platforms supported by Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The ToDo List Manager I recommend is ['Task Coach'](http://taskcoach.org/). It is available for Windows, Mac OS, Linux, BSD, iPhone, iPad and iPod Touch. You can load different 'ToDo' List Database files which may be cloud synchronised from you various OS's and there is even a [Portable App](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/task_coach_portable) version incase you need to update your activities from a locked down Windows PC.

Incidentally, Portable Apps is available for various platforms ... but that is another story.